# JOOMLA template showing blank page

Tags: joomla

i have successfully installed JOOMLA template. when i am viewing site, i am getting blank page. can anyone know what is the problem with the template ??

I have attached my xml and php files below.

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 3.2//DTD template 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/3.2/template-install.dtd">

<extension version="3.2" type="template" client="site">

<name>Varsha_Mahajan</name>
<author>varsha</author>
<authorEmail>rajeshkalluri26@gmail.com</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>http://www.varshamahajan.com/</authorUrl>
<copyright>© 2013 Varsha Mahajan All rights reserved.</copyright>
<license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
<version>3.2.0</version>
<creationDate>November 2013</creationDate>
<description>Main Template For Varsha Mahajan</description>



    <files>
        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>fonts</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
        <folder>scripts</folder>
        <file>favicon.ico</file>
        <file>index.html</file>
        <file>index.php</file>
        <file>template_thumbnail.png</file>
        <file>templateDetails.xml</file>

    </files>


<positions>
    <position>header</position>
    <position>slider</position>
    <position>footer</position>
</positions>

</extension>
```

this is my php file.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"
lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

<head>

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?    
>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?  
>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this-
>template ?>/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this- 
>template ?>/css/camera.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this-
>template ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<!-- top-bar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"  
style="background-color:#f8f8f8;">

   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header" style="xhtml" />

</div>

<!-- End top-bar -->

<div id="wrap">
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slider" style="xhtml" />
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post code from the index.php of your template? Also the above contents of your xml file should be inside `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 2.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="3.1" type="template" client="site">` and `</extension>`

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added php file and "above content" is already placed like you said.

Comment: no., i am not getting any errors :(

Comment: I have an idea but not 100%. in your `<html ...>` tag, try removing everything inside so you're simply left with `<html>`. Let me know what happens when you do this

Comment: @user2798220 - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think I might have found the issue here. You're calling things like `$this->template` but they haven't been defined properly.

Remove everything in your `<?php ?>` tags at the top and replace with this:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;
```

See what this does for you. Hope it helps

**Update:**

I found the problem. You forgot to add `<jdoc:include type="component" />` which loads the component view . Each page must have a component and not modules only.

So in your index.php, your code will look like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slider" style="xhtml" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

Please also use the code I provided in the first section of my answer ;)

Enjoy :)

Comment: @user2798220 - would you be able to provide a zip file of your template so I can test it on my localhost to find the issue?

Comment: give me your mail address bro. This is mine., rajeshkalluri26@gmail.com

Comment: @user2798220 - chat in here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43924/joomla-chat

Comment: ah I think you need a certain amount of reputation. My email is lodder15@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: have you got anything except blank page after the changes ?? I am getting the same old problem after the changes you made

Comment: yes, it all worked for me. I did make a few other changes so i can send you the zip file via email if you want

Comment: yup., please send me the file which is working for you., thanks :)

Comment: email sent with the zip

Comment: still blank page bro :(

Comment: Check any plugins you have added, disabling one at a time. ALso with white pages putting error reporting to development will sometimes reveal the problem.

Comment: Does it work with other templates? If so, it's a module in some position that doesn't exist in the other template; if it doesn't, it's a plugin. That will help narrow it down

Comment: @user2798220 - As Elin said, disable all 3rd party plugins 1 by 1. The template isn't now causing the problem as I have tested it on a fresh copy of Joomla 3.2 with the fixes made. there is something else on your site causing the problem. Also ensure you don't change any core Joomla files